# Log4j2.0 Asynchronous loggers causes OutOfMemory Java heap space

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, out-of-memory, log4j2

I configure my company's system to have all loggers be asynchronous by setting the system
 property `Log4jContextSelector` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector`. We use log4j 2.0.

There is no problem when I run a small input file through the system. But when I ran a bigger input file (our system is supposed to ran much bigger file than this), `OutOfMemoryError` is caused. Information is as below:

```
SEVERE: Exception processing: 14451294 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingB  ufferLogEvent@226dc6bf
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Then I increased the max heap size to 4 gigs (total physical memory is 8G) and another problem is caused:

```
SEVERE: Exception processing: 775221 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent@1c6b80a9
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: are u auditing something? can u post a sample code if possible?

Answer (score 2):

The Log4J team is aware of this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-414

---

Update 2018-2-2:

The original problem and the above JIRA ticket were raised 5 years ago against Log4j 2.0-beta9.

This is many years later. The Log4j2 community is about to release Log4j 2.11. Several memory leak bugs have been fixed since version 2.0-beta 9.

If anyone experiences this problem with a recent version of Log4j2 please raise a new JIRA ticket since this should not happen.